# trace method calls in java

Tags: java, trace, instrumentation, javassist

I am trying to trace method calls in java, currently I am using javassist library and my code is:

```java
for (CtMethod meth : methods) {
String method = meth.getName();
try {
                    meth.instrument(new ExprEditor() {
                        public void edit(MethodCall m) throws CannotCompileException { 
                            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                            StringBuffer bufferEnd = new StringBuffer();
                            String formatMessage = "String instMessage=new java.text.MessageFormat(\"{0},{1},{2}, has started execution,{3},{4}\").format(new String[]{\""
                                    + "returnType" + " " + meth.getLongName()
                                    + "\",\"" + cc.getSimpleName() + "\",\"" + method
                                    + "\", new java.util.Date().toString()"
                                    + ",java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getId()+\"\"});";
                            buffer.append(formatMessage);
                            buffer.append("org.springframework.samples.jpetstore.domain.logic.Log.trace( instMessage);");
                            String formatMessageEnd = "String instMessageEnd=new java.text.MessageFormat(\"{0},{1},{2}, has finished execution,{3},{4}\").format(new String[]{\""
                                    +"returnType" + " " + meth.getLongName()
                                    + "\",\"" + cc.getSimpleName() + "\",\"" + method
                                    + "\", new java.util.Date().toString()"
                                    + ",java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getId()+\"\"});";
                            bufferEnd.append(formatMessageEnd);
                            bufferEnd.append("org.springframework.samples.jpetstore.domain.logic.Log.trace(instMessageEnd);");
                            String start = buffer.toString();
                            String stop = bufferEnd.toString();

                            m.replace("{ try {" + start + " $_ = $proceed($$); } finally { " + stop + " } }");
                        }
                    });
                } catch (CannotCompileException e) {
                    System.out.println("******error:" + cc.getSimpleName() + "  -  " + method);
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

that's worked for me except for getter methods, for example if I have class called A with getB() method It still like the original without instrument, any idea how can I fix this.
**note** I will appreciate if you have another method to get method calls (without using  AOP) to get for example :

```
ClassA.method() **called** ClassB.method() at date()
ClassB.method() **return to** ClassA.method() at date()
```

Comment: Javassist leads developers astray with the idea of transforming *compiled code* in terms of *source code* fragments. It may lead to quick success with trivial examples, followed by a stall for any nontrivial task. You may rather use ObjectWeb ASM or the perhaps easier to use Byte Buddy which settles atop it, but in either case, getting knowledge about how bytecode actually works, is unavoidable. Well, profiling tools which can provide you full traces do exist, including free ones, so you don’t have to implement your own…

Answer (score 0):

Over the years, I have found this is one of the most challenging Java problems, to get a framework or library to do. We have to use AOP or reflection, please also try AspectJ

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).